# Get central meridian, PyProj?

Tags: python, pyproj

I am using PyProj and I am trying to find a way how to get Central Meridian and Latitude of the center of the zone for my State Plane coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972600/get-central-meridian-pyproj

I believe your answer is in pyproj 2.2.0 with the CRS class: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/v2.2.0rel/api/crs.html

```py
>>> import pyproj
>>> pyproj.__version__
'2.2.0'
>>> crs = pyproj.CRS("ESRI:102719")
>>> crs
<Projected CRS: ESRI:102719>
Name: NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Feet
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (US survey foot)
- N[north]: Northing (US survey foot)
Area of Use:
- name: USA - North Carolina
- bounds: (-84.33, 33.83, -75.38, 36.59)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Feet
- method: Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)
Datum: North American Datum 1983
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
>>> crs.coordinate_operation
CONVERSION["NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Feet",
    METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
        ID["EPSG",9802]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",33.75,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8821]],
    PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-79,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8822]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",34.3333333333333,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8823]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",36.1666666666667,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8824]],
    PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",2000000.00261667,
        LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
        ID["EPSG",8826]],
    PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
        LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
        ID["EPSG",8827]],
    ID["ESRI",102719]]
>>> crs.coordinate_operation.params
[Param(name=Latitude of false origin, auth_name=EPSG, code=8821, value=33.75, unit_name=degree, unit_auth_name=EPSG, unit_code=9102, unit_category=angular), Param(name=Longitude of false origin, auth_name=EPSG, code=8822, value=-79.0, unit_name=degree, unit_auth_name=EPSG, unit_code=9102, unit_category=angular), Param(name=Latitude of 1st standard parallel, auth_name=EPSG, code=8823, value=34.3333333333, unit_name=degree, unit_auth_name=EPSG, unit_code=9102, unit_category=angular), Param(name=Latitude of 2nd standard parallel, auth_name=EPSG, code=8824, value=36.1666666667, unit_name=degree, unit_auth_name=EPSG, unit_code=9102, unit_category=angular), Param(name=Easting at false origin, auth_name=EPSG, code=8826, value=2000000.00262, unit_name=US survey foot, unit_auth_name=EPSG, unit_code=9003, unit_category=linear), Param(name=Northing at false origin, auth_name=EPSG, code=8827, value=0.0, unit_name=US survey foot, unit_auth_name=EPSG, unit_code=9003, unit_category=linear)]
>>> crs.coordinate_operation.params[0]
Param(name=Latitude of false origin, auth_name=EPSG, code=8821, value=33.75, unit_name=degree, unit_auth_name=EPSG, unit_code=9102, unit_category=angular)
>>> crs.coordinate_operation.params[0].name
'Latitude of false origin'
>>> crs.coordinate_operation.params[0].value
33.75
```

I should clarify that:

- latitude_of_projection_origin == lat_0 == Latitude of false origin
- longitude_of_projection_origin == lon_0 == longitude_of_central_meridian == Longitude of false origin

To demonstrate:

```py
>>> crs.to_proj4()
'+proj=lcc +lat_0=33.75 +lon_0=-79 +lat_1=34.3333333333333 +lat_2=36.1666666666667 +x_0=609601.220000001 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs +type=crs'
```